# how to automate flight calender page using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select date which is two months later. The code which I tried is:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("departuredatetime")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-datepicker-div\"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]")).click();

driver.findElement(By.id("returningdatetime")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-datepicker-div\"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]")).click();
```

This is website code:

```
<a class="ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all" data-handler="next" data-event="click" title="Next">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e">Next</span>
</a>
```

Comment: please add HTML of that page.

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I am unable to change months in calender. Calender show two months at a time when clicked